# Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"

Tags: javascript

Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"

I am using MongoDB atlas

Index.js

```
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import postRoutes from "./Routes/posts.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/posts", postRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

mongoose
.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
.then(() => {
app.listen(PORT, console.log(Server is running on port ${PORT}));
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

---

.env file

```
CONNECTION_URL =
"mongodb+srv://<UserName>:<Password>@cluster0.v5qzigz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

PORT = 4000;
```

---

it works fine if i do not use .env File. Process.env.CONNECTION_URL is not working ?

Comment: `.env`: no spaces, no newlines, no semicolons. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 1):

I also had the exact same problem while following a course. Then I remembered on my last project it worked. So I went to look at the code on my last project then a solution popped up that helped me and could probably help you.

Please try to delete your dotenv file and make it again. Then try to make the connection variable(remove the strings) again and make show your code editor doesn't highlight with any color. (it must be plane light black the whole variable) then try to save it and see if it works.

This worked for me I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If the `<Username>` or `<Password>` includes those following characters, simply replace them.

`:` `/` `?` `#` `[` `]` `@`

Comment: Neither the <UserName> nor the <Password> contains any of these characters

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the variable is not formatted correctly in `.env`.

Remove the spaces, the quotes, and the semi-colon at the end.

This

```
CONNECTION_URL =
"mongodb+srv://<UserName>:<Password>@cluster0.v5qzigz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Becomes this

```
CONNECTION_URL=mongodb+srv://<UserName>:<Password>@cluster0.v5qzigz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Then the connection should work

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL).then(()=>{
    console.log('Atlas DB Connected...' )
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Atlas DB connection failed...', err )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

please check env file properly if deploying on heroku or any other platform as a service. In case you miss it you will receive this error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34434056)